# Ошибка Java:modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Tags: java, static

```
public class summa {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
   int param1,param2,sum;
    param1=input.nextInt();              
     param2=input.nextInt();
      sum=param1+param2;
       System.out.println(sum);
      }
     }






file.java on line 2: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class _runeatuj.summa
    public static void main(String[]args) {
                       ^
      modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
    1 error
```

Консоль с сайта codefights,подключенные библиотеки по умолчанию:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

Гуглил на эту тему но так и не понял в чём проблема,разъясните,пожалуйста

[image: скриншот]

Всем спасибо,разобрался,задача решается таким кодом

```
int add(int param1, int param2){

    return param1+param2;
}
```

Comment: Либо вы нам чего то не договариваете и это не весь код либо ... да нет все таки вы скорее не договариваете

Comment: Я указал всё,как есть.Вот прикрепил скриншот, всё тоже самое.

Comment: Может дело в том, что в задании написано ясно: `write a function...`, а вы мало того, что пишете её внутри класса, так ещё обзываете `static main`. Читайте условие внимательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из сообщения об ошибке очевидно, что `static` разрешено использовать только для объявления переменных.

P.S. Так же вам сделали подсказку, что нужно написать функцию `helloWorld(String)`, а не метод `main(String[])`